# java.sql.Clob reading : weird results b/w MySQL and Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc

I got an unified JDBC code for reading/writing large texts. Column is CLOB on Oracle and TEXT on MySQL. The following code

```
java.sql.Clob aClob = resultSet.getClob(COLUMN_NAME);
java.io.InputStream aStream = aClob.getAsciiStream();
int av = aStream.available();
```

gives relevant value on MySQL (Connector/J 5.0.4) but zero on Oracle (Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.2). `Clob.length()` fortunately gives correct value on both and `InputStream.read()` up to -1 works too, so there are other ways of obtaining the data in unified way.

[Javadoc gives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) this weird note:

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

So which driver is right? And no, i don't want to drag vendor-specific packages into the code :-) This question is JDBC neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to say that both drivers were right.

The Javadoc for the `available()` method appears to suggest that the value returned is an estimate of how many bytes the InputStream currently has cached and can return to you without an I/O operation.  How many bytes it has cached, and how it does any caching, would seem to me to be an implementation detail.  The fact that these values are different merely suggests that the two drivers are implemented differently.  Nothing in the Javadoc for the `available()` method suggests to me that either driver is doing anything wrong.

I'd guess that the Oracle driver doesn't cache any data from the `CLOB` immediately after executing the query, so that might be why the `available()` method returns 0.  However, once data has been read from the stream, the `available()` method for the Oracle driver no longer returns 0, as it seems Oracle JDBC driver has been to the database and fetched some data out of the `CLOB` column.  On the other hand, MySQL seems to be a bit more proactive in actually fetching data out of the TEXT column as soon as the query has finished executing.

Having read the Javadoc for the `available()` method I'm not sure why I'd use it.  What are you using it for?

Comment: The more i am reading the javadoc, the more it makes sense. The intended usage was a cycle, reading by one byte until available is zero. I didn't expect it to return zero on the first call. But i guess the key word in javadoc is "blocking". Which means that reading the first byte on Oracle would take significantly more time than on MySQL. Well, i already did it different way.